# Some problem of comparing two multidimensional lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Thanks for seeing my problem.
I designed to make a_list and erase every element in b_list if b_list have one.
But It doesn't work properly. It only works except a_list[0].
What is happening in my code?

```
a_list = [[0, 1], [0, 2]]
b_list = [[0, [0, 1], [0, 2], '3', [0, 4]], ['1', [0,1], [0, 2], [0, 3], '4', [0, 5]]]

for i in b_list:
    for j in a_list:
        temp = [k for k in i if k != j]
    print(temp)

>>> 0, [0, 1], '3', [0, 4]]
    ['1', [0, 1], [0, 3], '4', [0, 5]]
```

In this result, I cannot understand why [0, 1]s are in there!!!???

I want result like this

```
>>> [0, '3', [0, 4]]
>>> ['1', [0, 3], '4', [0, 5]]
```

PLZ help me.

Comment: In your inner loop, you are creating two lists. The first one won't have [0,1] in it - but you are not printing it. The second time through the loop you are reassigning to temp, but this list has just the [0,2] removed. That is the one that gets printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. You can use `not in` for the elements of `b_list` to check their existence in `a_list`.

```
a_list = [[0, 1], [0, 2]]
b_list = [[0, [0, 1], [0, 2], '3', [0, 4]], ['1', [0,1], [0, 2], [0, 3], '4', [0, 5]]]

for i in b_list:
    temp = [j for j in i if j not in a_list]
    print(temp)

# [0, '3', [0, 4]]
# ['1', [0, 3], '4', [0, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list comprehension like this:

```
[[i for i in l if i not in a_list] for l in b_list]
```

This returns:

```
[[0, '3', [0, 4]], ['1', [0, 3], '4', [0, 5]]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your fabulous solution. I really know that I have to do much more study.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is your code **overwriting** `temp` each time you iterate an item in `a_list`, so when `a_list = [[0, 1], [0, 2]]`, your `temp` will only contain the result of filtering out `[0, 2]`. Here's the modification of your code:

```py
a_list = [[0, 1], [0, 2]]
b_list = [[0, [0, 1], [0, 2], '3', [0, 4]], ['1', [0,1], [0, 2], [0, 3], '4', [0, 5]]]

for sub_list in b_list:
    temp = []
    for item_b in sub_list:
        not_in_a = True
        for item_a in a_list:
            not_in_a &= item_b != item_a
        if not_in_a:
            temp.append(item_b)
    print(temp)
```

If you are looking for concise code, I believe other answers can help you. I am just pointing out what's went wrong with your code.

Comment: Your comment arise many thought in me. Thank you very very much.